# Slick - MySQL Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick, play-slick

I'm using the Play Framework (2.3.1) together with Slick (play-slick version 0.8.0-M1) and a MySQL Database (5.5.28).

One of my queries results in a MySQLSyntaxErrorException:

```
Preparing statement: select x2."id", x2."course_id", x2."trainee_id", x2."transaction_id" from "trainee_grouptraining_GroupBooking" x2 where x2."course_id" = 1
```

The problem appears to be with the double quotation marks, since other queries work just fine and they use single quotation marks like the following:

```
Preparing statement: select x2.`id`, x2.`courseLanguage`, x2.`date`, x2.`description`, x2.`duration`, x2.`kind`, x2.`maxParticipants`, x2.`name`, x2.`courseType_id`, x2.`trainer_id` from `Course` x2 where x2.`id` = 1
```

What can i do about this?

Comment: Are you using the type-safe api? There may be something wrong with your driver setup. Are you casting anything?

Comment: Im not casting and I'm not sure what you mean by type-safe api. Could you please tell me how to find out if somethings wrong with driver setup?

This is in my application.conf:

db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/sportify_dev"
db.default.user=root
db.default.password=""

Comment: could you provide a minimal sample project on github that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 9):

I guess you are importing

```
scala.slick.driver.JdbcDriver.simple._
```

You should import

```
scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver.simple._
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is using per default backticks to quote identifiers. You could use the [SQL Mode ANSI_QUOTES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_ansi_quotes) to enable double quotes

> **ANSI_QUOTES**
>
> Treat " as an identifier quote character (like the ` quote
>   character) and not as a string quote character. You can still use “`”
>   to quote identifiers with this mode enabled. With ANSI_QUOTES enabled,
>   you cannot use double quotation marks to quote literal strings,
>   because it is interpreted as an identifier.

or simply use backticks.

Comment: Setting it to ansi_quotes mode did work. However i still think it's strange that slick sometimes uses backticks and sometimes quotation marks.